# Sharepoint update excel file with base64 content in Azure Logic Apps?

Tags: excel, sharepoint, base64, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have an Azure Logic App that takes file content, encodes it into base64, and sends it to an Azure Function. Afterwards, the Function returns the manipulated Excel data in base64 format.

How can I take this new data and write it to a SharePoint file using 'Update file?' I currently am using this method but the output comes out with some of the correct data being scattered amongst jibberish. Same result with `decodeBase64` instead of `base64ToBinary`.

```js
 "Update_file": {
    "inputs": {
      "body": "@{base64ToBinary(body('...'))}",
      "host": {
        "connection": {
          "name": "..."
        }
      },
      "method": "put",
      "path": "..."
    },
    "runAfter": {},
    "type": "ApiConnection"
  }
```

[image: jibberish excel file]

I know the issue is with writing as opposed to my excel data being corrupted because I copied and pasted the output of my function to `x.txt` and ran `$ base64 -d -i x.txt >> mtestfile.xls` which resulted in the output I wanted.

I now attempted to output my data in a URI like `data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,<data>` and used `dataUriToBinary` which had the same result. Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: The most important part of the code is not there: how are you manipulating the Excel file? You cannot simply push some binary content into an Excel file and expect it to be correct; you need to use an Excel library like [ClosedXML](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML/).

Comment: Will edit and add now.

Comment: @rickvdbosch Please let me know what you think of my changes. For reference, I am using the xlsx nodejs package.

Comment: Still dealing with this issue, not sure which direction to move in